# Results Undefined in Salesforce LWC

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I have a list of integers and trying to assign each on javascript variables. But I am getting undefined results:

[image]

I am stuck on the following codes:

**periodLWC.html**

```
<template> 
    
    <lightning-combobox
        class="slds-m-bottom_small slds-m-left_small"
        name="fiscalYear"
        label="Fiscal Year"
        value={yearValue}
        placeholder="--None--"
        options={yearOptions}
        onchange={findOrgFYData}>
    </lightning-combobox>  
       
</template>
```

**periodLWC.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';


import getFYOrgData '@salesforce/apex/PeriodController.getFYOrgData'; 


export default class periodLWC extends LightningElement {

  
    @track periodData = [];

    @track error;

    @track orgFYData = [];

    @track orgFYstart1;
                    
    @track orgFYend1;
   
    @track yearValue = '--None--';

    @track yearOptions = [
        {value: 'FY2019', label: 'FY2019'},
        {value: 'FY2020', label: 'FY2020'},
        {value: 'FY2021', label: 'FY2021'}
    ];

    
    findOrgFYData(event) {
        const orgYear = event.target.value;

        var orgStartFY = orgYear.substring(2);

        console.log('Trimmed fiscal year value is===>' + orgStartFY);

        var orgStartFYInt = parseInt(orgStartFY, 10);

        console.log('Converted integer is===>' + orgStartFYInt);

        if(orgStartFYInt) {
           
            getFYOrgData({orgStartFYInt})
            .then(result => {
                if(result) {
                    console.log('Returned results===>' + result);      

                    this.orgFYData = result;
                    console.log('Passed result' + this.orgFYData);
                    this.orgFYstart1 = result.fyStartYear;
                    console.log('Start Year' + this.orgFYstart1);
                    this.orgFYend1 = result.fyEndYear;
                    console.log('End Year' + this.orgFYend1);  
                }
                
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            })    
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

**PeriodController.cls**

```
public class PeriodController{

       @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

       public static List<Integer> getFYOrgData(Integer orgStartFYInt) {

              List<Integer> intList = new List<Integer>();
              List<AggregateResult> aggList = new List<AggregateResult>();

              aggList = [SELECT CALENDAR_YEAR(EndDate) endYear,Id,CALENDAR_YEAR(StartDate) startYear,Type FROM Period 
                     WHERE Type = 'Year' AND CALENDAR_YEAR(StartDate) =: orgStartFYInt
                     GROUP BY Id, Type, CALENDAR_YEAR(EndDate), CALENDAR_YEAR(StartDate)  ];
                

              for(AggregateResult agg : aggList) {
                            
                  Integer fyStartYear = (Integer) agg.get('startYear');
                  Integer fyEndYear = (Integer) agg.get('endYear');
       
                  intList.add(fyStartYear);
                  intList.add(fyEndYear);              
              }
                     
              return intList;  
                           
       }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning the values in the `result`, not properties. so you need to use the result index to get value. in fact `result.fyStartYear` and `result.fyEndYear` do not exist instead use :  `result[0]` and `result[1]`

```
    findOrgFYData(event) {
        const orgYear = event.target.value;

        var orgStartFY = orgYear.substring(2);

        console.log('Trimmed fiscal year value is===>' + orgStartFY);

        var orgStartFYInt = parseInt(orgStartFY, 10);

        console.log('Converted integer is===>' + orgStartFYInt);

        if(orgStartFYInt) {
           
            getFYOrgData({orgStartFYInt})
            .then(result => {
                if(result) {
                    console.log('Returned results===>' + result);      

                    this.orgFYData = result;
                    console.log('Passed result' + this.orgFYData);                    
                    this.orgFYstart1 = result[0];                    
                    console.log('Start Year' + this.orgFYstart1);                   
                    this.orgFYend1 = result[1];
                    console.log('End Year' + this.orgFYend1);  
                }
                
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            })    
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: this line `this.orgFYend1 = result.result[1];` does not return anything, so I modified it to this `this.orgFYend1 = result[1];`. But you have just given me the idea on how to do it. Both values are now returned, thanks! :))

Comment: My bad it was just ````result[1]````, I updated the answer.